Wong Visual Studio path in 'flutter build windows'
Steps to reproduce
Run flutter build windows
Actual results
wrong visual Studio path when I run flutter build windows
PS E:\Projects\flutter\picbed> flutter build windows

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 17 2022

  could not find specified instance of Visual Studio:

    E:/windowsSdk/Visual Studio


Building Windows application...                                    215ms
Unable to generate build files

the visual studio path here is diffrenet with that in flutter doctor
My Visual studio was installed in E:\\windowsSdk\\studio which shows in flutter doctor
I am worderning is there any way to specisy visual studio path?
Logs
PS E:\Projects\flutter\picbed> flutter build windows

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 17 2022

  could not find specified instance of Visual Studio:

    E:/windowsSdk/Visual Studio


Building Windows application...                                    215ms
Unable to generate build files

Flutter Doctor output
[ +132 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +48 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LegacyCanvasKitRemover' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +88 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +112 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +106 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +2 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +106 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +106 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +105 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +6 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +102 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[        ] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[ +109 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[ +164 ms] executing: [E:\sdk\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +65 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 2 weeks ago
[  +11 ms] executing: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java --version
[  +97 ms] Exit code 0 from: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java --version
[        ] openjdk 17.0.11 2024-04-16
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+0--11852314, mixed mode)
[   +5 ms] executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe -format json -products *
-utf8 -latest -version 16 -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project
[  +50 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe -format json -products
* -utf8 -latest -version 16 -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project
[        ] [
             {
               "instanceId": "dbbed5e2",
               "installDate": "2024-08-15T13:05:01Z",
               "installationName": "VisualStudio/17.11.0+35208.52",
               "installationPath": "E:\\windowsSdk\\studio",
               "installationVersion": "17.11.35208.52",
               "productId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community",
               "productPath": "E:\\windowsSdk\\studio\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe",
               "state": 4294967295,
               "isComplete": true,
               "isLaunchable": true,
               "isPrerelease": false,
               "isRebootRequired": false,
               "displayName": "Visual Studio Community 2022",
               "description": "功能强大的 IDE，供学生、开放源代码参与者和个人免费使用",
               "channelId": "VisualStudio.17.Release",
               "channelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/channel",
               "enginePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual
               Studio\\Installer\\resources\\app\\ServiceHub\\Services\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service",
               "installedChannelId": "VisualStudio.17.Release",
               "installedChannelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/channel",
               "releaseNotes":
               "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.11#17.11.0",
               "resolvedInstallationPath": "E:\\windowsSdk\\studio",
               "thirdPartyNotices": "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=661288",
               "updateDate": "2024-08-15T13:05:01.5213776Z",
               "catalog": {
                 "buildBranch": "d17.11",
                 "buildVersion": "17.11.35208.52",
                 "id": "VisualStudio/17.11.0+35208.52",
                 "localBuild": "build-lab",
                 "manifestName": "VisualStudio",
                 "manifestType": "installer",
                 "productDisplayVersion": "17.11.0",
                 "productLine": "Dev17",
                 "productLineVersion": "2022",
                 "productMilestone": "RTW",
                 "productMilestoneIsPreRelease": "False",
                 "productName": "Visual Studio",
                 "productPatchVersion": "0",
                 "productPreReleaseMilestoneSuffix": "8.0",
                 "productSemanticVersion": "17.11.0+35208.52",
                 "requiredEngineVersion": "3.11.2177.7163"
               },
               "properties": {
                 "campaignId": "",
                 "channelManifestId": "VisualStudio.17.Release/17.11.0+35208.52",
                 "includeRecommended": "1",
                 "nickname": "",
                 "setupEngineFilePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\setup.exe"
               }
             }
           ]
[   +2 ms] executing: reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0 /v
InstallationFolder
[  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0 /v
InstallationFolder
[        ] HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0
               InstallationFolder    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
[   +5 ms] executing: E:\androidSdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +40 ms] [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22631.3958], locale zh-CN)
[   +1 ms]     • Flutter version 3.24.0 on channel stable at E:\sdk\flutter
[        ]     • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ]     • Framework revision 80c2e84975 (2 weeks ago), 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
[        ]     • Engine revision b8800d88be
[        ]     • Dart version 3.5.0
[        ]     • DevTools version 2.37.2
[ +193 ms] List of devices attached
[  +36 ms] executing: E:\androidSdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +55 ms] List of devices attached
[+3186 ms] [✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[  +36 ms] [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[        ]     • Android SDK at E:\androidSdk
[        ]     • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
[        ]     • ANDROID_HOME = E:\androidSdk
[        ]     • Java binary at: D:\JetBrain\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
[        ]     • All Android licenses accepted.
[  +18 ms] [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[        ]     • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[  +19 ms] [✓] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.0)
[        ]     • Visual Studio at E:\windowsSdk\studio
[        ]     • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35208.52
[        ]     • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0
[  +19 ms] [✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[        ]     • Android Studio at D:\JetBrain\Android Studio
[        ]     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
[        ]     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
[        ]     • android-studio-dir = D:\JetBrain\Android Studio
[        ]     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
[  +23 ms] [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.2)
[        ]     • IntelliJ at D:\JetBrain\IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
[        ]     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
[        ]     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
[        ]        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
[  +22 ms] [✓] Connected device (3 available)
[        ]     • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.22631.3958]
[        ]     • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.114
[        ]     • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 127.0.2651.98
[  +21 ms] [✓] Network resources
[        ]     • All expected network resources are available.
[        ] • No issues found!
[   +8 ms] "flutter doctor" took 5,380ms.
[ +308 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 264ms
[        ] Running 1 shutdown hook
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[ +265 ms] exiting with code 0


try to reinstall visual studio with Desktop development with C++ selected, or you can try flutter clean command, some times it helps a lot

I got some help from Official Github Issues. Just run flutter clean, and it works
